# What happens to unregistered users' comments/answers after migration?

Tags: support, comments, migration, unregistered-users

Recently a question of mine was migrated from unix.se to SO. After a few hours I noticed that all answers and comments from a given user had disappeared (there were only 3 or 4 users who contributed). I could be wrong but I don't *think* he is registered on SO.

What happens to comments and answers from a user registered on site A but not on site B when a question is migrated from site A to B?

He may have deleted them himself (I don't know why he would have), in which case it's moot, but if SO deleted them, that kind of stinks because they were valuable comments (and also added context to some conversation).

Comment: Based on Adam's answer, when I say "unregistered on site X" I actually mean "they don't have a profile on site X yet". Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: I noticed twice that comments are disappeared during migration https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/337035/answers-comments-were-not-copied-during-migration-to-another-site. It seems not related, does author registered on site or not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There may be some term overloading going on here. We refer to a profile as being "registered" when the user signed up via OpenID and "unregistered" when they opted to ask or answer anonymously and only provided a (possibly fake) email address and a name.

In general, when your post (question or answer) is migrated to a site where you don't have a profile, you will get notified of the migration and when you create a profile on that site that post will get automatically associated with that profile.

This is conditional on a couple things:

1. That you have a registered profile on the source site. (You can register your unregistered profile first.)
2. That you use the same login credentials on the destination site and allow you profiles to be linked to the same network account.

Your reputation earned from the migrated post will be applied to the profile on the destination site with the exception (I believe) of bounties.

With all that said, all comments and answers are preserved during the migration except for the comments on the question that happen to include a URL to the destination site since in the vast majority of cases those comments just say "you should post it on http://othersite.stackexchange.com" or something along  those lines.

While it's possible for comments or answers to be removed by moderators, in this case it looks like [the answer you are referring to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19747664/105971) was deleted by its poster:

[image]

Why they removed the answer is anybody's guess, though. Sorry. My best theory is that since another answer was accepted, they felt that it was better anyway and theirs was no longer needed.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry about the confusing use of terms.

Comment: @JasonC No worries. I just wanted to make sure we were on the same page.

Comment: “all comments and answers are preserved during the migration except for the comments on the question that happen to include a URL to the destination site”. I noticed that comment disappeared after migration ( even from the original question timeline) https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/337035/answers-comments-were-not-copied-during-migration-to-another-site