# Answers/comments were not copied during migration to another site

Tags: support, status-bydesign, migration, deleted-answers

My question [What are the correct pronouns for referring to someone whom I have never met in person when the gender is apparent?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/228470/what-are-the-correct-pronouns-for-referring-to-someone-whom-i-have-never-met-in) has a banner

> migrated from english.stackexchange.com  Oct 25 at 0:44.

I remember that original question on english.stackexchange https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/516397/?noredirect=1 had at least 2 answers and a few comments, that are not visible now on a new site.

According to
[What is migration and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work/10250#10250)

> Migration  preserves the current revision of the question, all its
> answers, any comments on any post, as well as most of the votes. ….
> Answers on the origin site are deleted immediately upon question
> migration. ... The answers will be visible on the destination
> question.

Can you explain, why answers/comments were not copied for this question?

UPDATE: I noticed another example of the same issue: I’ve created a [question in Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72362178/) and received one comment. Then the question was migrated to DBA [Can transactions on main table be delayed/deadlock when maintenance transaction on temporal table runs?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/312511/can-transactions-on-main-table-be-delayed-deadlock-when-maintenance-transaction), and the comment disappeared from the question, including [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72362178/timeline) and from my notifications menu.

Comment: Based on the [timeline](https://ell.stackexchange.com/posts/228470/timeline) two answers have been migrated.

Comment: Thanks @rene, I wasn’t aware about timeline. And in the “view oldest answers first” mode I was (again) confused that accepted answer is shown first regardless of the actual time of creation order

Comment: Comments aren't meant to last. Probably a mod cleaned them up before migration.

Comment: @Luuklag, the comment was useful, it could considered as an answer. A human moderator wouldn’t intentionally remove such comment. From the [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72362178/timeline) it seems that migration occurred automatically based on review on close votes queue

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One of the answers was deleted by its author prior to migration. Deleted answers aren't migrated.

Comment: Your info about self-deleted answer and rene’s link to timeline explain why I missed the answers, but I also remember couple of comments to my question, that I couldn’t see now. Were they also deleted by the same person, as it was conversation with him/her, and I suggested to write an answer instead of a sequence of comments?

Comment: @MichaelFreidgeim If those comments were under the answer, they would have been deleted with the answer. I cleaned up one comment under the question recommending [interpersonal.se] for your question since it was migrated instead to ELL and it seems like you were more focused on the language than the interpersonal relationships.

Comment: Yeah, there were a dozen comments on the question, all deleted prior to migration @michael